# Algorithm to assign Exams to Rooms?

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem that I have no idea what it is or how to solve it. I know there is a name for the problem (after it is known, the title could be changed to reflect it).

Its somewhat of getting a perfect fit for a particular list based on a passed formula. For eg.

I have 2 lists of objects. One list of rooms and one list of exams. For each exam, I loop through all available rooms, execute a formula (which returns a value from 0-1), 1 meaning its a good fit, and assign the highest one to the exam. I continue the loop over and over to find the best fit (which may lead to infinite loop).

I am trying to avoid using a genetic algorithm to solve this. Anyone got any idea what the name of the problem is and also a possible solution?

ps. Can an admin rename the title if I do not get the chance to?

Comment: You can change the title yourself by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5871608/edit) link.

Comment: That seems to be a [partitioning problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  Wikipedia will tell you more about how to solve it.